# to whom/which, for which

Tags: relative-pronouns

Consider the following sentence:

> Sometimes even if we try hard to come up with an idea, the result of "**which**" carried out is in vain.

Should it be *which* or *it*?

Also, how can I make sentences using the structure of "with whom/which", "to whom/which"? I don't know how to do this. I know that it is supposed to include two sentences in one. The "to which/whom" sentence is often long and full of information.

Comment: They're both incorrect, and it's not even clear to me what you're trying to say.

Comment: thanks for telling me. I meant sometimes even if you try hard, it doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean, even if you try hard sometimes the effort you made is in vain?

Then the sentence you have in mind could be :

" Sometimes even if we try hard to come up with an idea, the result of that what is carried out is in vain. "

But I really think that's not a good sentence and just overcomplicating things.

Comment: yes, that's what I meant.